# UITableView dynamic cells with a UITextField GCed?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView in which I create my own Cells by adding UIViews to the cell based on the index which is needed as I have about 15 very different cells in one table.

This all works fine, except when I have a UITextField; when I click on the text field, the application crashes which, what looks like something has been garbage collected and now it's still being used.

To reproduce , you simple make a UITableView with a cellForRowAtIndexPath which returns a Cell view to which you add, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method a UITextField. When the UITableView appears you will see the text fields (and anything else you might have added to it), but clicking on the text field will crash when it becomes first responder.

I'm probably missing something trivial where it is logical somehow but I cannot find references to it from others (or i'm not searching correctly of course).

Comment: Post some code and we can help you.  I have a similar scenerio which works perfectly.

Comment: Ok, I'll pull out the code and put it here.